# Where is padding in Bootstrap 4x lists defined?

Tags: list, firefox, bootstrap-4, padding

I am changing a Joomla site over from Bootstrap 3x to Bootstrap 4x (front-end only at this time).

I have noticed that lists, `ol` and `ul` in Bootstrap 4x have a large padding but when you inspect the code, `padding` is not in the code. So how is the `padding` getting into the lists?

Please see screenshot from Bootstrap 4x's own page ([Bootstrap 4 Lists](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/reboot/#lists)) about lists:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This type of issue bugs me too but it is usually straighforward to override any unwanted default Bootstrap or template styling via a custom CSS file that won't get overwritten by future updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers have their own basic stylesheets. See the `padding-inline-start` property defined by `user agent stylesheet`?

[image]

It's part of your browser's own stylesheet. Typically they're very minimal but they're the reason we have things like [css reset](https://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/).

**Edit:**
Apparently Firefox does not show user agent styles by default. You can change this behavior by opening inspector settings and enabling "Show Browser Styles" option.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but how do you view the user agent stylesheet? When I use Firefox's inspector it only shows up the website-specific code as shown on my screenshot.

Comment: Amended my answer.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much.